# select de nome no banco com C#

Tags: c#, select

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em C# windows form em 3 camadas. O meu problema é: tenho um `datagridview` para receber os dados do banco e um `textbox` para ser digitado o nome que quero buscar no banco, mas como estou fazendo em 3 camadas não estou usando o `textbox` na minha consulta sql que normalmente vejo na internet assim:

> "select * from tabela where nome like '%" + txt_nome +"%'"

Queria saber como faço essa consulta, já tentei diversas formas mas sem resultado.

Código do banco`

```
    public DataTable Consultar(DadosPessoa nome)
    {
        try
        {
            conexao = new MySqlConnection(conecta_db);

            MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM funcionario WHERE nome_func like @nome", conexao);
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nome", nome.Nome_Func);

            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(comando);

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            da.Fill(dt);

            return dt;
        }
        catch (Exception erro)
        {

            throw erro;
        }
    }`
```

Esse é o meu código da classe que acessa o banco:

```
public DataTable Consulta_Dao(string nome)
{
    try
    {
        dao = new Classe_Dao();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        dt = dao.Consultar(nome);

        return dt;
    }
    catch (Exception erro)
    {

        throw erro;
    }
}
```

Esse é o do botão que pesquisa:

```
private void btn_pesquisar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e, string nome)
{
    try
    {
        ClasseBll bll = new ClasseBll();

       nome = txt_pesquisar.Text;

        dg_dados.DataSource = bll.Consulta_Dao(nome);

    }
    catch (Exception erro)
    {

        throw erro;
    }
}
```

Comment: E qual é o problema ou erro?

Comment: Fala pra gente qual é, e onde é que ocorre o erro. Pois analisando o código assim por cima, não aparenta ter problemas. Só diria para você alterar a query, não concatenar ela, e sim utilizar o comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("nome", nome);

Comment: o problema e que quando eu clico no botão para pesquisar ele não me responde em nada.

Comment: Parece tudo bem. Para mim, é a query que não está a encontrar ninguém com esse nome. Mostra o código do "Consultar".

Comment: já editei e coloquei o código do banco

Comment: @AécioCleysson Verifique também se o botão possui o evento de **Click** para o método **btn_pesquisar_Click** ou se está vazio. Essa verificação pode ser feita no arquivo .design ou ainda dependendo do editor, na parte de eventos do botão.

Answer (score 0):

`Consultar` espera um parâmetro do tipo `DadosPessoa`, sendo que você está passando `nome` que é uma `string`.

Answer (score 0):

Imagino que o erro está na passagem de parâmetro para a pesquisa. Tente dessa forma.

```
public DataTable Consultar(string nome)
{
    try
    {
        conexao = new MySqlConnection(conecta_db);

        MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM funcionario WHERE nome_func like @nome", conexao);
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nome", nome);

        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(comando);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        da.Fill(dt);

        return dt;
    }
    catch (Exception erro)
    {

        throw erro;
    }
}`
```